# Is it possible to encrypt integers?

Tags: python, encryption, steganography

So my program is a Stenography program, it inserts an image into another image, and I'm trying to encrypt the data before inserting it into the cover image. However, most encryption modules expect strings and I'm trying to pass integers.

I've tried converting to string then encrypting, but the encryption is full of special characters and letters so converting back to integer for insertion is impossible.

Anyone know if I can somehow encrypt an integer? It doesn't have to be very secure.

I'm trying to add the encryption in here:

```
for i in range(0,3):
    #verify we have reached the end of our hidden file
    if count >= len(Stringbits):
        #convert the bits to their rgb value and appened them
        for rgbValue in pixelList:
            pixelnumbers1 = int(''.join(str(b) for b in rgbValue), 2)
            #print pixelnumbers1
            rgb_Array.append(pixelnumbers1)
        pixels[x, y] = (rgb_Array[0], rgb_Array[1], rgb_Array[2])
        print "Completed"
        return imageObject.save(output)
```

I've been trying to encrypt `pixelnumbers1` then add it in. But `pixels[x, y]` requires an integer.

Below is the rest of the code in-case:

```
def write(mainimage, secret, output):
    #string contains the header, data and length in binary
    Stringbits = dcimage.createString(secret)
    imageObject = Image.open(mainimage).convert('RGB')
    imageWidth, imageHeight = imageObject.size
    pixels = imageObject.load()
    rgbDecimal_Array = []
    rgb_Array = []
    count = 0

    #loop through each pixel
    for x in range (imageWidth):
        for y in range (imageHeight):
            r,g,b = pixels[x,y]
            #convert each pixel into an 8 bit representation
            redPixel = list(bin(r)[2:].zfill(8))
            greenPixel = list(bin(g)[2:].zfill(8))
            bluePixel = list(bin(b)[2:].zfill(8))
            pixelList = [redPixel, greenPixel, bluePixel]

            #for each of rgb
            for i in range(0,3):
                #verify we have reached the end of our hidden file
                if count >= len(Stringbits):
                    #convert the bits to their rgb value and appened them
                    for rgbValue in pixelList:
                        pixelnumbers1 = int(''.join(str(b) for b in rgbValue), 2)
                        #print pixelnumbers1
                        rgb_Array.append(pixelnumbers1)
                    pixels[x, y] = (rgb_Array[0], rgb_Array[1], rgb_Array[2])
                    print "Completed"
                    return imageObject.save(output)

                #If we haven't rached the end of the file, store a bit
                else:
                    pixelList[i][7] = Stringbits[count]
                    count+=1
            pixels[x, y] = dcimage.getPixel(pixelList)
```

Comment: Most encryption systems work with either arbitrary binary data, strings, or both. "Integer" is not a concept they can handle as the format for integers varies wildly from one system to another. You can always convert your integers to strings, encrypt it, then bake it in. Encrypted data is often raw binary, and stringifying it requires encoding with Base64 or something similar.

Comment: Integers, strings etc, are just interpretations of binary values.  If you can encrypt one type, you can do them all.

Comment: @tadman what do you mean by "bake it in" ?

Comment: Presuming you're talking about [steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) and not [stenography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shorthand), "baking in" is the process of embedding the encrypted data into another medium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how computers see any type of data.

You read the bytestream of a file, which looks like a string to you, but each character is actually a byte, a value from 0 to 255. It just happens that some of them are represented by conventional string characters. Try `print(bytes(range(256))` to see them all. Most standard encryption functions take a byte array in and spit a byte array out. It just happens that you get more of the bytes that don't have a "simple" representation. But they are not any less bytes than what you initially fed in.

Your dcimage.py has the following:

```
#get the file data in binary
fileData = bytearray(open(secret, 'rb').read())#opens the binary file in read or write mode
for bits in fileData:
    binDataString += bin(bits)[2:].zfill(8)#convert the file data to binary
```

There is nothing that stops you from doing this

```
fileData = open(secret, 'rb').read() # a bytes object by default
encryptedData = myEncryptionFuction(fileData) # also a bytes object
for bits in encryptedData:
    # ...
```

**VERY IMPORTANT:** You add a null byte at the end of your message so your extracting sequence knows when to stop. If you compress, or encrypt, a string (or byte array), it is likely a null byte will be part of that stream, which will break your extraction sequence. In that case you want to use a [header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44484791/python-steganographer-file-handling-error-for-non-plain-text-files/44485507#44485507) that tells your program ahead of time how many bits to extract.

---

By the way, bytes are already in an integer form.

```
>>> some_byte = b'G'
>>> some_byte[0]
71
```

You're better of using [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) for steganography. You take bytes and instead of using bitwise operations between them and your pixels, you turn both to binary strings, slice and stitch them and then turn them back to integers.

```
def bytes_to_bits(stream):
    for byte in stream:
        for shift in range(7, -1, -1):
            yield (byte >> shift) & 0x01

secret_bits = tuple(bytes_to_bits(encoded_data))

# simplified for one colour plane
for x in range(image_height):
    for y in range(image_width):
        # (pixel AND 254) OR bit - the first part zeroes out the lsb
        pixels[x,y] = (pixels[x,y] & 0xfe) | secret_bits[count]
        count += 1

# -------------------------------------

# to extract the bit from a stego pixel
bit = pixel & 0x01
```

Comment: I think I sorta got it, I did what you said.


`fileData1 = open(secret, 'rb').read()
 encryptedData = cipher_suite.encrypt(fileData1)
 encryptedData = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(encryptedData),16))`


I converted to binary and then tried to add it into my bitString 
`bitString = binName + nullDelimiter + binDataSize + nullDelimiter + encryptedData`


But when trying to save it in my getPixel function i get a:

invalid literal for int() with base 2: '0000000b'

Comment: i'm relatively still a novice at best with Python, so please bare with me.

Comment: @PaulCabz You probably have a mistake in your integer-to-bitstring conversion. `bin()` gives you a string that starts with `'0b'` and somehow that 'b' got tagged along for the ride. It's impossible to tell where you went wrong with the whole traceback and relevant code, but if you can't figure it out, you should ask a new question. This is one is about what you originally asked; encrypting binary data.

Comment: @PaulCabz I updated the an answer with some information that may become relevant should you decide to encrypt your message.

Answer (score 0):

Integers can be encryted by adding each digit to a random integer stream in the range 0 to 9, subtracting 10 when the sum > 9.  Modulo should be avoided because of ambiguities.